# Эмуляция клавиши мыши в игровом окне

Tags: c++, opengl

Как можно реализовать искусственно нажатую клавишу мыши в окне opengl игры? Может есть какие-либо ссылки на работу с библиотекой opengl, или код.

Comment: Библиотека opengl служит только для рисования и не обрабатывает ввод никаким боком. Для этого следует использовать надлежащие системное API.

Comment: Но все равно не понимаю, или может я не так использую winapi, работает во всех окнах кроме окна в игре

Comment: Точно так же как и не в opengl.